# Can't see MapBox React Native GL annotations

Tags: javascript, ios9, mapbox, react-native, mapbox-gl

I am building an app using React Native and want to use the [MapBox GL Component](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl) to render a map and add annotations. I am trying to implement [this example](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/example.js) from the github repo.

I've followed the installation instructions as best I can, but when the map loads, the annotations are not there. I get this:

[image]

This error in Xcode (3 times):

```
Oct 14 20:45:08  MapBoxDemo[9268] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. Backtrace:
      <-[UIStatusBarItemView updateContentsAndWidth]+33>
       <-[UIStatusBarItemView initWithItem:data:actions:style:]+477>
        <+[UIStatusBarItemView createViewForItem:withData:actions:foregroundStyle:]+134>
         <-[UIStatusBarLayoutManager _createViewForItem:withData:actions:]+163>
          <-[UIStatusBarLayoutManager _prepareEnabledItemType:withEnabledItems:withData:actions:itemAppearing:itemDisappearing:]+36
           <-[UIStatusBarLayoutManager prepareEnabledItems:withData:actions:]+92>
            <-[UIStatusBarForegroundView _setStatusBarData:actions:animated:]+797>
             <-[UIStatusBarForegroundView setStatusBarData:actions:animated:]+332>
              <__51-[UIStatusBar _prepareToSetStyle:animation:forced:]_block_invoke+360>
               <+[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:]+65>
                <-[UIStatusBar _prepareToSetStyle:animation:forced:]+866>
                 <-[UIStatusBar _requestStyleAttributes:animationParameters:forced:]+391>
                  <-[UIStatusBar requestStyle:animationParameters:forced:]+437>
                   <-[UIStatusBar requestStyle:animated:forced:]+90>
                    <-[UIStatusBar _evaluateServerRegistration]+250>
                     <__45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke+590>
                      <-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]+544>
                       <-[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]+1967>
                        <-[UIStatusBarWindow setStatusBar:]+288>
                         <-[UIApplication _createStatusBarWithRequestedStyle:orientation:hidden:]+340>
                          <-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:]+950>
                           <-[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:]+188>
                            <-[FBSSerialQueue _performNext]+192>
                             <-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource]+45>
                              <__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__+17>
                               <__CFRunLoopDoSources0+556>
                                <__CFRunLoopRun+867>
                                 <CFRunLoopRunSpecific+488>
                                  <-[UIApplication _run]+402>
                                   <UIApplicationMain+171>
                                    <main+111>
                                     <start+1>
```

and this one (just once):

```
2015-10-14 20:45:09.328 [warn][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] 'Warning: Failed propType: typeChecker is not a function. (In \'typeChecker(\npropValue,\ni,\ncomponentName,\nlocation,\npropFullName + \'[\' + i + \']\')\', \'typeChecker\' is undefined) Check the render method of `MapBoxDemo`.'
```

I have set the map center to the same position as the first annotation so it should definitely be in view.

All other functionality seems to work (recentering the map, zooming etc). I have also seen the [example used here](https://rnplay.org/apps/KR9WOw) and it works (on iOS 8 at least).

Any ideas? Could it be iOS9 related? My code is below:

```
    'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var MapboxGLMap = require('react-native-mapbox-gl');
var mapRef = 'mapRef';
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  StatusBarIOS,
  View
} = React;

var MapBoxDemo = React.createClass({
  mixins: [MapboxGLMap.Mixin],
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      center: {
        latitude: 40.72052634,
        longitude: -73.97686958312988
      },
      zoom: 11,
      annotations: [{
        coordinates: [40.72052634, -73.97686958312988],
        "type": "point",
        title: 'This is marker 1',
        subtitle: 'It has a rightCalloutAccessory too',
        rightCalloutAccessory: {
          url: 'https://cldup.com/9Lp0EaBw5s.png',
          height: 25,
          width: 25
        },
        annotationImage: {
          url: 'https://cldup.com/CnRLZem9k9.png',
          height: 25,
          width: 25
        },
        id: 'marker1'
      }, {
        coordinates: [40.714541341726175,-74.00579452514648],
        "type": "point",
        title: 'Important!',
        subtitle: 'Neat, this is a custom annotation image',
        annotationImage: {
          url: 'https://cldup.com/7NLZklp8zS.png',
          height: 25,
          width: 25
        },
        id: 'marker2'
      }, {
        "coordinates": [[40.76572150042782,-73.99429321289062],[40.743485405490695, -74.00218963623047],[40.728266950429735,-74.00218963623047],[40.728266950429735,-73.99154663085938],[40.73633186448861,-73.98983001708984],[40.74465591168391,-73.98914337158203],[40.749337730454826,-73.9870834350586]],
        "type": "polyline",
        "strokeColor": "#00FB00",
        "strokeWidth": 4,
        "strokeAlpha": .5,
        "id": "foobar"
      }, {
        "coordinates": [[40.749857912194386, -73.96820068359375], [40.741924698522055,-73.9735221862793], [40.735681504432264,-73.97523880004883], [40.7315190495212,-73.97438049316406], [40.729177554196376,-73.97180557250975], [40.72345355209305,-73.97438049316406], [40.719290332250544,-73.97455215454102], [40.71369559554873,-73.97729873657227], [40.71200407096382,-73.97850036621094], [40.71031250340588,-73.98691177368163], [40.71031250340588,-73.99154663085938]],
        "type": "polygon",
        "fillAlpha":1,
        "strokeColor": "#fffff",
        "fillColor": "blue",
        "id": "zap"
      }]
     };
  },

  render: function() {
    StatusBarIOS.setHidden(true);
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <Text style={styles.text} onPress={() => this.addAnnotations(mapRef, [{
          coordinates: [40.73312,-73.989],
          type: 'point',
          title: 'This is a new marker',
          id: 'foo'
        }, {
          "coordinates": [[40.749857912194386, -73.96820068359375], [40.741924698522055,-73.9735221862793], [40.735681504432264,-73.97523880004883], [40.7315190495212,-73.97438049316406], [40.729177554196376,-73.97180557250975], [40.72345355209305,-73.97438049316406], [40.719290332250544,-73.97455215454102], [40.71369559554873,-73.97729873657227], [40.71200407096382,-73.97850036621094], [40.71031250340588,-73.98691177368163], [40.71031250340588,-73.99154663085938]],
          "type": "polygon",
          "fillAlpha": 1,
          "fillColor": "#000",
          "strokeAlpha": 1,
          "id": "new-black-polygon"
        }])}>
          Add new marker
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.text} onPress={() => this.selectAnnotationAnimated(mapRef, 0)}>
          Open first popup
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.text} onPress={() => this.removeAnnotation(mapRef, 0)}>
          Remove first annotation
        </Text>
        <MapboxGLMap
          style={styles.map}
          direction={0}
          rotateEnabled={true}
          scrollEnabled={true}
          zoomEnabled={true}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          ref={mapRef}
          accessToken={'pk.eyJ1IjoibWF0dGhld2JldGEiLCJhIjoiY2lmcGZxdnpnMDFqOXVlbHllazRwcWxqZSJ9.M0lbiLNHcd-WT-Ps_MkCvA'}
          styleURL={'asset://styles/streets-v8.json'}
          centerCoordinate={this.state.center}
          userLocationVisible={true}
          zoomLevel={this.state.zoom}
          onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
          onRegionWillChange={this.onRegionWillChange}
          annotations={this.state.annotations}
          onOpenAnnotation={this.onOpenAnnotation}
          onRightAnnotationTapped={this.onRightAnnotationTapped}
          onUpdateUserLocation={this.onUpdateUserLocation} />
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  map: {
    flex: 1
  },
  text: {
    padding: 3
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MapBoxDemo', () => MapBoxDemo);
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem. Seems an issue with "coordinates" key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there any errors in Xcode? Also, it might be a good idea to remove unnecessary code from and just try and add annotations to the map.

If you could also try and run your code on react playground, I might be able to help debug this better, here is an example: https://rnplay.org/apps/KR9WOw

Comment: Hi. Have updated my question and forked your code. Put my code in and I'm not seeing markers - which suggests I'm doing something wrong. Code is here: https://rnplay.org/apps/94SIyw

Comment: Aha, comparing my code to yours the annotation latitude and longitude are separate keys on the object. Mine are an array with a key of 'coordinates' (as per example on the repo). I will go and tweak m app code now and report back. Has the syntax changed?

Comment: I've updated them in my app now and can see the markers. What is the syntax to create a polyline/polygon though? The coordinates array of arrays doesn't seem to work. (Thanks for your help btw : D )

Comment: @matthewbeta I wonder if you figured out what is the syntax to create a polyline?

Comment: @Jaec Not yet. Was going to pick it up again in a few days and take another look to see if the docs etc had been updated but I guess they haven't...

Comment: I've recreated my xcode project, now using cocoapods to add the mapbox-gl component and it's now working with "coordinates" key.